# $a\sin(b) = \sin(c)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Context:

> $\sin(x^2) = \sin^{2}(x)$
>
> $\sin^{-1}(\sin(x^2)) = \sin^{-1}(\sin^2(x))$ --> $x^2 = \frac{\pi}{2} - 2\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(x))$ thanks to Angelo's post on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4635255/can-expressions-such-as-sin-1-sin2x-be-simplified-analytically/4635321#4635321).
>
> $\sin^{-1}(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(x)) = \frac{\pi - 2x^2}{4}$
>
> $±\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos(x) = \sin(\frac{\pi - 2x^2}{4})$
>
> $±\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2}) = \sin(\frac{\pi - 2x^2}{4})$

At this point in solving, a theorem similar to that of the natural logarithm; $a\ln(b) = \ln(b^a)$ would be ideal. I am aware that there are some 'multiple angle formula' theorems related to the trigonometric functions; an example being $\sin(2x) = 2\sin(x)\cos(x)$ - the coefficient has been moved **outside** the sine function - but in this situation I need to move the coefficient **inside** the function - so that I can cancel the sines on both sides with arcsine - how can I derive a sine theorem to express this?

$$a\sin(b) = \sin(c)$$

Another way to rephrase the question would be: How do I simplify the following expression?

$$\sin^{-1}(a\sin(b))$$

Comment: The theorem you want does not exist.

Comment: $\sin(x^2) = \sin^2(x)$ is false in general.  Well, it's true for $x=0$ and an infinite set of discrete values, $1.364412963\ldots, \; 2.565941347\ldots,\; 3.06912621739\ldots,\; \ldots$.

Comment: If $-1 \le a \le 1$, you could say $$a \sin(b) = \sin(\arcsin(a)) \sin(b) = \frac{\cos(b - \arcsin(a)) - \cos(b+\arcsin(a))}{2}$$
but that's hardly a "simplification"..

Comment: You are chasing a chimera. You are not going to find some nice neat expression for the solutions to $\sin(x^2) = \sin^2(x)$. Most transcendental equations (i.e. involving functions more complex than polynomials) that you can write down easily *do not have elementary formulas for their solutions*. When they are expressible at all by named functions, those functions are actually just sweeping the nastiness under a rug (i.e. label) rather than removing it. But then, that is also exactly what exponentials and radicals do. You have to resort to numerical approximations to evaluate them.